# Execute Windows Batch Command at targeted machine locally

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

My jenkins host machine and targeted test machine (slave) are located at different network.

I would like Jenkins to trigger the job to run the .bat file at the targeted test machine (slave) locally.

1. At Jenkins Host machine: no python, no Robot Framework, winapp driver and libraries
2. At targeted machine: python, Robot Framework, winapp driver and libraries installed, test can be run successfully.

I prepared the Run_RF_TestScript.bat, which it runs successfully when I double-click it locally.

```
xcopy /s /e /c /q /h /r /k /y "G:\RF_Scripts\Run_RF_TestScript.bat" "C:\project-test"
cd C:\project-test
Run_RF_TestScript.bat
```

However, when the script is being called by Jenkins, I did not see the cmd prompt at the targeted machine. Then error occurred:

```
Building remotely on testvm192201 in workspace C:\workspace\test_Simulation_v2.1_RF
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
[test_Simulation_v2.1_RF] $ cmd /c call C:\temp\jenkins9067096848698669129.bat

C:\workspace\test_Simulation_v2.1_RF>xcopy /s /e /c /q /h /r /k /y "G:\RF_Scripts\Run_RF_TestScript.bat" "C:\project-test" 
1 File(s) copied

C:\workspace\test_Simulation_v2.1_RF>cd C:\project-test 

C:\project-test>Run_RF_TestScript.bat

C:\project-test>echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\project-test>cd C:\EwTest 

C:\EwTest>robot --outputdir C:\workspace\test_Simulation_v2.1_RF\reports ./Testcase/Test-001-About.robot 
==============================================================================
Test-001-About                                                                
==============================================================================
TC001-01-About :: Launch App-check status OK-check version            [ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021A7C92F5E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /session
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021A7C92F3A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /session
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021A7C984160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /session
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Save Appium Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No application is open
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Save Appium Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No application is open
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Save Appium Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No application is open
| FAIL |
Setup failed:
MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4723): Max retries exceeded with url: /session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021A7C984C40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

Also teardown failed:
Several failures occurred:

1) No application is open

2) No application is open
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: The process "WinAppDriver.exe" not found.
Test-001-About                                                        | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\workspace\test_Simulation_v2.1_RF\reports\output.xml
Log:     C:\workspace\test_Simulation_v2.1_RF\reports\log.html
Report:  C:\workspace\test_Simulation_v2.1_RF\reports\report.html

C:\EwTest>exit 0 
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level C:\workspace\test_Simulation_v2.1_RF\reports to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\test_Simulation_v2.1_RF\builds\9\htmlreports\HTML_20Report
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Where is the web server?  You're trying to connect to port 4723 on the Jenkins host (127.0.0.1).  You need to substitute the IP address of whatever machine is serving port 4723.

Comment: whe appium web server is at targeted machine, i tried to change it to the actual IP address, http://192.168.202.128:4723 then local test failed 
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001621B11B5B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /session
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))

Comment: 192.168.xxx.xxx is a local network address.  If these machines are on different networks, then you will have to have a public IP address.  This may involve port forwarding through a router.